# MySQL update one row when another changes

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with products.

```
artID   artName stock   order

1   cables *100 0
2   cables *1   75
```

What should I do to asociate these 2 rows and get the stock in sync. The provider sells the cables in bulks on 100 units, and the retail store sells then as unit.
The idea is: when "cables *1" run nearly out of stock set the order row to 1 so the employees know they need to buy more cables.
I have a relations table defining multiple types of relations between articles (if this server for something)
Obviously this is a very simplified version of the db.

I'm working with php. But any language agnostic idea will serve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using a trigger?

See

[MySQL Trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)

and

[Databasedesign-resource](http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/mysql-triggers.html)

Comment: That was blitsig, if you know what I'm saying :P

Comment: I was afraid that the answer will be triggers. The thing is, triggers don't like me. I try to understand them, but they keep ignoring me. Do you know any in dept tutorial? this one from database design is a good start, but i know I will need something more, and the MySQL documentation serves only as reference.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you should create a trigger on your table that will be fired on UPDATE and will change the value after updating first row.

Here's the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) of how to use triggers in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks RaYell. Same question to you. Do you know any in dept tutorial? this one from database design is a good start, but i know I will need something more, and the MySQL documentation serves only as reference.

Comment: There's plenty of tutorials in Google, just type: `MySQL trigger tutorial`